# Assign a point to the class member

Tags: c++, opencv

i trying to implement the following link http://in.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/motion-based-multiple-object-tracking.html in opencv and c++.
I have created a class say ex:

```
class assign
{
    vector <int> id;
    vector <int> area;
    vector<Point> centroid;
};
```

After this i have created an object

```
assign id;
```

Now i want to assign the centroid value and other values too. what i tried is

```
id.centroid (p);
```

where p is a "point" But i'm getting error for this. I don't know where i'm going wrong.

Comment: Remember to post your error messages!

Comment: What is your programming background? This is not the way it works in C++. You have two options: Either you make the member `centroid` `public` or (which would be the preferred way) you define setter and getter member functions, which allow you to access the member.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`centroid` is a `private` member of class `assign`. If you want to access it directly, you should make it public

```
class assign
{
public:
    vector<Point> centroid;
    //...
};
```

And if you want to add a `Point` into `centroid`, you should

```
id.centroid.push_back(p);
```

Comment: Note that in the above declaration, `centroid` is private so you will get an error anyway unless you declare it public.

Comment: Oh, did not know that. Then we should delete the comments, I will.

Comment: @songyuanyao Thanks that helped me.!! Earlier i had defined it as public and used id.centroid(p) to assign a value. Was that wrong?? we have to use push_back(p)???;

Comment: @Arjun Yes, you have to use `push_back(p)`, because you're not assigning a `Point` to `vector` (and you can't), you're adding an element into the vector. And if you want to assign a vector, see @exilit 's answer.

Comment: @songyuanyao Yeah i got it now.!! Thank u !!

Comment: @songyuanyao  Why is that i'm getting error while printing the value of the area?? cout<<"area"<<id.area;    "binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::vector<_Ty>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)"

Comment: @Arjun `std::vector` doesn't support `operator<<` directly. You can loop it and print every element by yourself, such as `for (auto v: id.area) std::cout << v << " ";`, or use `std::copy`, such as `std::copy(id.area.begin(), id.area.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));`

Comment: @songyuanyao "cout<<"centroid"<<id.centroid;" But when i tried this the values are getting printed. Okay i ll try it.

Comment: @songyuanyao i tried this  "for(int  m=0;m<id.area1.size();m++){
  cout<<"area"<< id.area1(m); } but didn't get. "term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments"

Comment: @Arjun Change `id.area1(m)` to `id.area1[m]`.

Comment: @songyuanyao Yes i got it.!!

Comment: @songyuanyao But why did it display for cout<<" "<<id.centroid; without using loop???

Comment: @Arjun It's weird...Did someone define an `operator<<` just for `vector<Point>`?

Comment: @songyuanyao ha ha ha.!! I don't know i'm still a learner of c++. I'm still in doubt why??

Comment: @Arjun If you can create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/) for it, you might ask a new question for it.

Answer (score 1):

The main answer is already given by songyuanyao. What I want to add is a possible solution which allows you to use the member variables like you already tried it.

If you want to get and set the member `centroid` with `id.centroid(p)` you could go with the following class declaration:

```
class Assign
{
public:
    vector<Point> centroid();
    void          centroid(vector<Point> c);
private:
    vector<Point> m_centroid;
};
```

The definition might then look like this:

```
// getter
vector<Point> Assign::centroid() {
    return m_centroid;
}

// setter
void Assign::centroid(vector<Point> c) {
    m_centroid = c;
}
```

Now if you use `id.centroid(p)` to set the member the overloaded setter will be called and will set the variable. If you call `p = id.centroid()` (empty parameter list) the overloaded getter will be called and will return the current `m_centroid`.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the previous answers; if you want to expand on your class this can be done for you during construction of your object.

```
class Assign {
private:
    std::vector<int> m_vIds;
    std::vector<int> m_vAreas;
    std::vector<Vec2> m_vCentroids;

public:
    Assign();  // Default Constructor Same As What You Have But Not Declared.
    Assign( int* pIds, int* pAreas, int* pCentroids ); // Create By Using Pointers
    // Create By Passing In Either Pre Filled Vectors Or Even An Empty 
    // Vectors To Be Filled Out Later. Passes By Reference. This Will
    // Also Set The Variables That Are Passed In From The Caller.
    Assign( std::vector<int>& vIds, std::vector<int>& vAreas, std::vector<Vec2>& vCentroids );

    // Since You Are Using Vectors Within This Class It Is Also Good To
    // Have A Destructor To Clear These Out Once The Object Is Done And
    // Ready To Be Destroyed Or Removed From Memory
    ~Assign();
};

// The Destructor Would Look Like This
Assign::~Asign() {
    if ( !m_vIds.empty() ) {
        m_vIds.clear();
    }
    if ( !m_vAreas.empty() ) {
        m_vAreas.clear();
    }
    if ( !m_vCentroids.empty() ) {
        m_vCentroids.empty();
    }
} // ~Assign

// NOTE: I used Vec2 instead of point due to my use of programming
// 2D & 3D Graphics Rendering Engines; Most Graphics APIs and Libraries
// along with Most Math Libraries Will Not Have A Point Class; Most Will
// Use Vec2 or Vec3 - Vector2  or Vector3 & Vector4 Since in terms of
// memory they are exactly the same thing. It is up to you to know which
// objects are points or locations, and which are vectors as in forces,
// velocities, accelerations, directions, normals etc. The only major
// difference between a discrete Point Class or Structure versus a Vector
// Class is that the Vector Class usually has operations defined with it
// to do vector mathematics such as addition, subtraction, multiplication by
// value, multiplication by vector, division by value, division by vector,
// cross & dot product, comparisons, testing if vector is 0, setting it to
// be a normal vector, returning the magnitude or length and a few others.
// The general point class or object is usually just data values or
// simply coordinates without operations.
```